# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot convert 'InBlock' via asFinalized

Tags: polkadot-js, pallet, batch, uniques

I am trying to sign and send some transactions using the `batch` function.
Here are some code snippets for reproduction.

```
const nftMinting = async (item) => {
    try {
      let collection = 1
      
      const fromAcct = await getFromAcct()
      let txs = []
      txs.push(api.tx.uniques.create(collection, polkadotAccount))

      const nftAmount = 100
      const price = nftAmount > 0? Math.round(Number(item?.price) / nftAmount) : 0

      if (price > 0) {
        for (let index = 0; index < 100; index++) {
          txs.push(api.tx.uniques.mint(collection, index + 1, polkadotAccount))
          txs.push(api.tx.uniques.setPrice(collection, index + 1, price, polkadotAccount))
        }
      }

      await api.tx.utility.batch(txs).signAndSend(...fromAcct, ({ events = [], status, txHash }) =>{
        status.isFinalized
          ? toast.success(` Finalized. Block hash: ${status.asFinalized.toString()}`)
          : toast.info(`Current transaction status: ${status.type}`)
    
          // Loop through Vec<EventRecord> to display all events
          events.forEach(async ({ _, event: { data, method, section } }) => {
            if ((section + ":" + method) === 'system:ExtrinsicFailed' ) {
              // extract the data for this event
              const [dispatchError, dispatchInfo] = data
              console.log(`dispatchinfo: ${dispatchInfo}`)
              let errorInfo
              
              // decode the error
              if (dispatchError.isModule) {
                // for module errors, we have the section indexed, lookup
                // (For specific known errors, we can also do a check against the
                // api.errors.<module>.<ErrorName>.is(dispatchError.asModule) guard)
                const mod = dispatchError.asModule
                const error = api.registry.findMetaError(
                    new Uint8Array([mod.index.toNumber(), bnFromHex(mod.error.toHex().slice(0, 4)).toNumber()])
                )
                let message = `${error.section}.${error.name}${
                    Array.isArray(error.docs) ? `(${error.docs.join('')})` : error.docs || ''
                }`
                
                errorInfo = `${message}`
                console.log(`Error-info::${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
              } else {
                // Other, CannotLookup, BadOrigin, no extra info
                errorInfo = dispatchError.toString()
              }
              toast.warn(` Transaction Failed! ${section}.${method}::${errorInfo}`)
            } else if (section + ":" + method === 'system:ExtrinsicSuccess' ) {
              toast.success(`❤️️ Transaction successful! tx hash: ${txHash}, Block hash: ${status.asFinalized.toString()}`)
            }
          })
      })      
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error :: ', error)
    }
  }
```

But I got this error, unfortunately.

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot convert 'InBlock' via asFinalized`

[image]

Any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which line of the code posted does the error point at; the `toast.success(` Finalized. Block hash: ${status.asFinalized.toString()}`)` one? If so, I'd have a look at the generated JS; perhaps the `status.asFinalized.toString()` is moved outside the ternary or something?

Comment: The error occurs once I accept by entering the password on the polkadot js extension. The other words, I think it happens before running the status.asFinalized.toString() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `status?.type !== 'InBlock'` like this.

```
} else if (section + ":" + method === 'system:ExtrinsicSuccess' && status?.type !== 'InBlock' ) {
```

And I fixed it.

Comment: Ah, yeah, because you call `status.asFinalized.toString()` after that, and the status may well not be finalized yet.

Comment: By the way, why it occurs for `InBlock`? It has also `Ready`.